# perl function definition fails with uninitialized value

Tags: perl

My perl chops are a little stale so I'm probably missing something really obvious here, but I've added a small module to some older code CGI code to refactor common functions. Here is an excerpt of the module with the part that is giving me problems:

```
package Common;

use strict;
use warnings;
use base 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT_OK = (&fail_with_error);

sub fail_with_error {
    my ($errmsg, $textcolor) = @_;
    my $output = printf("<p><font color=\"%s\">ERROR: %s </font>/<p>", $textcolor, $errmsg);
    print($output);
    exit(1);
}
```

When I execute this module directly with `perl Common.pm` (or when I just import the function in test code, without even calling it) what I get is an uninitialized value error for `$errmsg` and `$textcolor` like this:

```
$ perl Common.pm
Use of uninitialized value $textcolor in printf at Common2.pm line 10.
Use of uninitialized value $errmsg in printf at Common2.pm line 10.
<p><font color="">ERROR:  </font>/<p>1
```

It would seem that perl is giving the warning because it is executing the subroutine code literally, but the nature of a subroutine is that it is abstracted so different values can be passed in correct? It would stand to reason these shouldn't have to be populated to pass interpreter warnings, but nonetheless something is wrong.

I've searched around, but this error is very common because in most cases the variable really is uninitialized. I can't seem to find anything that applies to this type of case.

Comment: As an aside, I think you want sprintf there rather than printf. Or combine the sprintf and print into a single printf.

Comment: Don't forget that a module must return a *true* value when it is run on its own, so you will normally need to add `1;` to the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks, I had seen the '1' before but did not know why it was there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because you're accidentally populating @EXPORT_OK with a call to fail_with_error: `&fail_with_error`, instead of the function name.  This calls `fail_with_errors` with the arguments populated from the current `@_` which happens to be empty - so naturally both the variables are uninitialized (and also your function doesn't get exported). The correct assignment uses just the subroutine name:

```
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( fail_with_error );
```

Comment: This fixed it, thanks. I had seen a couple of examples so was not sure of the syntax for EXPORT